# Область видимости

Tags: java

Имеется форма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее вызывается контекстное меню у кнопки “AND” (для каждой кнопки),  затем выбирается `Events – Action – ActionPerformed`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Почему подчеркиваются поля?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В данной области видимости полей **b1** и **b2** не существует.

Сделай их глобальными, т.е объяви внутри класса, а не методов. Однако все же внутри методов ты можешь переключать значения полей в зависимости от состояния переключателей на форме.

```
class Class {

    boolean b1 = false, b2 = false;

}
```

**Личная рекомендация: делай ассоциативные, мнемонические имена.**